# How to populate the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in my `datagridview` and I want to populate using `linq` in run-time:

I try this

```
var line = from li in dbdata.Production_lines select li;
grdEmp.Rows.Add();

(grdEmp.Rows[count].Cells["Line"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = line;
(grdEmp.Rows[count].Cells["Line"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ValueMember = "L_id";
(grdEmp.Rows[count].Cells["Line"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DisplayMember = "L_id";
```

But this didn't work. so how do I bind the data to `ComboBox` in my `DataGridView`

Comment: I though you're trying to add a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)grdEmp.Columns["Line"];

combo.DataSource = line;
combo.ValueMember = "L_id";
combo.DisplayMember = "L_id"; // I also suspect this should be a text column
```